# Twitter Bootstrap : a language div breaks the menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, menu, alignment

I'm having some difficuilties with Twitter Bootstrap menu + adding a language dropdown menu.

I want it to be displayed in one line. Unfortunately, adding a dropdown menu splits the menu into two lines.

How to fix it?
The example of the problem is here:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GGMWX/50/)

Adding `display:inline;` doesn't help everything to be displayed in one line.
And the proper order would be as standard:
Project Name_*Home*_About_*Contact****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___***Language*_Logged in as Username

Any ideas how to fix it properly?

Comment: Your layout is very similar to example in the docs. I've [recreated it](http://jsfiddle.net/GGMWX/55/) with no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all don't use divs in a nav where you could use lists (`<li>`).

If you want to display text in a navbar use:

```
  <span class="navbar-text">some text</span>
```

inside of the `<li>`-tags to align and style it properly.

Here is the correct markup for your nav:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GGMWX/57/)